# r- transforming columns, calling them by $name, using a loop

Tags: r, loops, character, eval, assign

imported tibble from textfile. Many numeric columns are imported as "chr". I guess it's because they contain a "," instead of a ".".
My goal is to write a loop which runs through the names of desired columns, replaces "," with "." and converts columns into "num".
Little example:

```
data <- data.frame("A1" =c("2,1","2,1","2,1"), "A2" =c("1,3","1,3","1,3"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F) %>% as.tibble() #example data
colname <- c("A1", "A2") #creating variable for loop

for(i in colname) {
    nam <- paste0("data$", i)
    assign(nam, as.numeric(gsub(",",".", eval(parse(text = paste0("data$",i))))) )
  }
```

Instead of overwriting the existing column, R creates a new variable:

```
data$A1 # that's the existing column as part of the tibble
[1] "2,1" "2,1" "2,1"
`data$A1` # thats just a new variable. mind the little``
[1] 2.1 2.1 2.1
```

I also tried to assign (<-) the new numeric values via eval, but that does not work either.

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("data$", i))) <- as.numeric(
gsub(",",".", eval(parse(text = paste0("data$",i)))))

Error: target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Any suggestions on how to transform? I have the same issue with other columns that I want to aggregate to a new variable. This variable should also be part of the existing tibble. I could do it by hand. This would take lots of time and probably produce many mistakes.
Thanks a lot!
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already working with the `tidyverse`, you can use `dplyr::mutate_at` and the `colname` variable you have already defined.

```
data %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = colname, 
            .funs = function(x) { as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x))  })
```